# Saving Users Scores

Tags: ios, iphone, save

Ola, I am trying to find a way to save user scores so when it is closed from the background it saves their scores and when open again it displays that score once again. By the way the thing Im saving is a tap counter so when they tap it has to add onto their previous score.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save:

```
int numberOfTaps = 42; // some number of taps
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfTaps] forKey:@"numberOfTaps"];
```

Retrieve:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int savedTaps = [[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"numberOfTaps"] intValue];
```

#### Updating For Further Information

Just to make it extremely easy:

Copy these methods somewhere in your .m

```
- (void) saveNumberOfTaps:(int)numberOfTaps {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfTaps] forKey:@"numberOfTaps"];
    NSLog(@"Saved numberOfTaps: %i", numberOfTaps);
}

- (int) getNumberOfTaps {
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"numberOfTaps"] intValue]) {
        int numberOfTaps = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"numberOfTaps"] intValue];
        NSLog(@"Getting numberOfTaps: %i", numberOfTaps);
        return numberOfTaps;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No taps saved yet");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then whenever you want to use these values, you can use the following:

```
// Save Taps
[self saveNumberOfTaps:14];

// Get Taps
int taps = [self getNumberOfTaps];
NSLog(@"taps retrieved: %i", taps);
```

Comment: What do i add to my .h file

Comment: You shouldn't have to add anything.

Comment: Its giving me 2 semantic errors and 1 parse error for the 2,3 line for save and load its giving me 2 semantic errors on both lines

Comment: I just ran this exact code with no problems, I think your problem is somewhere else.  Can you add more code to your question?

Comment: If 'NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];' is giving the error: 'redefinition of standardUserDefaults' then you are running both sections back to back. Remove this line.

Comment: On the third line that says 'standardUserDefaults' it has a parse issue and says 'Expected Identifier or "("'?

Comment: Your error is somewhere else. You have an open bracket somewhere.

Comment: I did what you said but when i double click home button and swipe it off the screen it goes back to 0?

Comment: I will add the image to my questoin

Comment: You modified the get method, copy it exactly.

Comment: Where are you calling [self saveNumberOfTaps:14];

Comment: where do i put the //save and //get taps?

Comment: Can you show me your entire .m file?  The problems are somewhere else, I really need to see the entire document.  Can you post the entire .m, or host it somewhere I can download?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, you set your counter to 0.  This means it's always going to start from zero.  replace your plus method with this:  - (IBAction)plus {
    [self saveNumberOfTaps:[self getNumberOfTaps]+1];
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [self getNumberOfTaps]];
}

Comment: Sweet it works thx but one more thing when i load the app it looks like it is at 0 but when you click it goes to the saved amount how do i load the saved amount?

Comment: Because you set it to 0 in viewdidload change: count.text = @"0"; to count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [self getNumberOfTaps]];

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just starting out, so try using NSUserDefaults. Once you need something more advanced, look into Core Data.